# Small greenhouse humidity maintenance

Tags: greenhouse, humidity

I have a 10x25 foot greenhouse and I am looking for a way to keep the humidity level up in the space.
I tried a second hand humidifier but it doesn't seem to be working very well.

I want to try using a Mr. Mister shower head humidifier, but keeping it on 24/7 will be too much. 
Does anyone know of a water hose timer that will turn on every X minutes and stay on for maybe 1 minute at a time?
Even better would be a water hose timer which activates based on humidity level.

Advice please.